# eloquent laravel parameter argument

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display a parameter argument in the URL address for my products. For example: `/product?brand=2&view=5`

This address is divided into two parts:

- The brand
- The number of product in display

##### `products` table (model name: `Product`)

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhoneX |
| 2 | SamsungNote8 |
| 3 | MiRedmi8 |
| 4 | MiPoco5 |
| 5 | MiX3Pro |
| 6 | SonyZ2 |
| 7 | MiX5Pro |
| 8 | MiX4Pro |
| 9 | MiX7Pro |

##### `brands` table (model name: `Brand`)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sony |
| 2 | Mi |
| 3 | LG |
| 4 | Samsung |
| 5 | iPhone |

##### `selects` table (model name: `Select`)

| product_id | brand_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 |

I want the product brand to be displayed by the parameter argument.

out: `/product?brand=2&view=5`

```
3: MiRedmi8
4: MiPoco5
5: MiX3Pro
7: MiX5Pro
8: MiX4Pro
```

##### `routes/web.php`

```php
Route::get('/product', 'ProductController@index');
```

##### `app/Models/Product.php`

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

##### `app/Models/Brand.php`

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

##### `app/Models/Select.php`

```php
class Select extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

##### `app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php`

```php
public function index()
{
    $view = request()->view ? request()->view : 20;

    $products = Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->where(function($query) {
            $brand = Request()->brand;

            if ($brand) {
                $query->Select::where('id', $brand)
                    ->whereIn(['id' => $brand]); 
            }
        })
        ->paginate($view);

    return view('index', compact('products'));
}
```

##### `resources/views/index.blade.php`

```html
@foreach($products as $row)
    {{ $row->id }} : {{ $row->title }}
@endforeach

{{ $products->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```

But it gives me an error saying that `Select` does not exist:

> Property [Select] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

How do I fix this error and display the product brand by the parameter argument?

Comment: `$query->Select::where(...)` - What? That's not how you query against your `Select` model... I'm surprised that even compiles. If you need to query against your `brand` or `select` tables, use a proper `join()` or the `whereHas()` method in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database layout makes no sense, if a `Product` has one `Brand` then a pivot table is not needed. Your `products` table should instead have a `brand_id` column.

However, working with what you have now, step one is to actually define your [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships):

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function brands() {
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class);
    }
}

class Brand extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Your `Select` model is a pivot model. It probably doesn't even need to be a model, but if it is, it should be defined [as a `Pivot`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) not a `Model`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
class Select extends Pivot
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function brand() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, relation: __FUNCTION__);
    }
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, relation: __FUNCTION__);
    }
}
```

Then I think your controller would look like this. `Builder::when()` executes a [conditional query](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#conditional-clauses) based on the value of its first argument. So if the query string variable is filled it will search and filter the relationship for an appropriate value. Note `request()->query()` is how you get [query string variables](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string).

```php
public function index()
{
    $view = request()->query("view", 20);

    $products = Product::orderBy("id")
        ->when(
            request()->query("brand"),
            function ($query) {
                $brand = request()->query("brand");
                $query
                    ->with(["brands", fn ($q) => $q->where("id", $brand])
                    ->whereHas("brands", fn ($q) => $q->where("id", $brand);
            },
            function ($query) {
                $query->with("brands");
            }
        )
        ->paginate($view);

    return view('index', compact('products'));
}
```